# More precision in comparing two dates, that are two hours appart

Tags: java, datetime, assertion

Can this be tested with more precision? This is a simple function that calculates `executionStartTime` as two hours behind `currentTime`.

Function below works, but I would like a function that is more precise.

```
@Test
public void testCalculateExecutionStartTime() {
    Date currentTime = new Date(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochSecond() * 1000);
    Date executionStartTime = proxy.calculateExecutionStartTime(properties.getMessageConfiguration().getExecutionStartTime());

    Assert.assertTrue(currentTime.after(executionStartTime));
}
```

Comment: You could check the time before and after the call, and verify that two hours after the returned time is in between the times before and after.

Comment: Since you can use java.time, the modern Java date and time API (`ZonedDateTime`, `ZoneOffset`), do that exclusively and forget everything about `Date`. `Date` is poorly designed and long outdated. In case you cannot alter the return type of `calculateExecutionStartTime`, convert the `Date` you get from it to `Instant` and check the `Instant`.

Comment: What is `properties.getMessageConfiguration().getExecutionStartTime()`? In which way does the calculation depend on this?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking, because the code that you show does not do what you say that it does. And how accurate do you want it to be? Java Date has at least millisecond accuracy, on many systems even microsecond accuracy.

Comment: @fishinear The outdated `Date` class had millisecond precision, nothing more. The modern`Instant` and friends have nanosecond precision (9 decimals on the seconds; though their `now` methods are not (usually) that precise).

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that `calculateExecutionStartTime` is returning a time that is two hours ago compared to the time you call the method, and this is what you want to test. In my first suggestion I am further assuming that you can change the method to return a modern `Instant` instead of an outdated `Date`. Since you can use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, this would immediately look like an easy improvement.

The challenge is that the call may take some milliseconds, even some seconds, and we don’t know at what point in time during the call it is reading the clock. So there is no testing using `assertEquals` with the time that we expect. Instead we read the clock *before* and *after* the call. Then our test can rely on the method reading the clock at some point between our two calls. In most cases this will allow us to test the returned time with just a small margin. The idea was already presented by Dawood ibn Kareem in a comment.

```
@Test
public void testCalculateExecutionStartTime() {
    Instant timeBefore = Instant.now();
    Instant executionStartTime = proxy.calculateExecutionStartTime(
            properties.getMessageConfiguration().getExecutionStartTime());
    Instant timeAfter = Instant.now();

    Duration expectedTimeAgo = Duration.ofHours(2);
    Assert.assertFalse(executionStartTime.isBefore(timeBefore.minus(expectedTimeAgo)));
    Assert.assertFalse(executionStartTime.isAfter(timeAfter.minus(expectedTimeAgo)));
}
```

Note the use of `Instant.now()` for reading the clock. You don’t need `ZonedDateTime` nor `ZoneOffset`.

If you cannot change the return type of `calculateExecutionStartTime`, just convert the `Date` you get from it:

```
    Instant executionStartTime = proxy.calculateExecutionStartTime(
                    properties.getMessageConfiguration().getExecutionStartTime())
            .toInstant();
```

The rest is exactly as before.